# Insert into mysql from dynamic form

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this code and I can't get the $txt2 to be inserted into mysql!
BUT the $tele2 is inserted, also when having multi rows from the dynamic form!.

But the $txt2 will not be inserted into DB.

Can someone see what the problem is. I think that it is some place in the foreach

**This is the action post page!!**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false): 

$day = $_POST['day'];

$month = $_POST['month'];

$text=$_POST['txt'];
$tele=$_POST['tele'];

include("db.php");

foreach($tele as $a => $b){
    $a+1;

$txt2 = $_POST['text'][$a]; 
$tele2 = $_POST['tele'][$a]; 


$sql_ins="INSERT INTO SmsSend (`PHONENUM`, `TEXT`) VALUES 
    ('".$tele2."','".$txt2."')";
$res_ins1=mysql_query($sql_ins);

} 

?>
```

---

**Sending my info from this dynamic form:**

```
<fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Besked og bruger info</legend>
                <p> 
                    <input type="button" value="Tilføj bruger" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Fjern bruger" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 

                </p>
               <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
<td>
<label for="txt">text</label>
<input type="text" required="required" maxlength="160" name="txt[]">
</td>
<td>
<label for="tele">TELE</label>
<input type="text" required="required" maxlength="8" name="tele[]">
</td>
</p>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="clear"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). This problem is very solvable by employing prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$_POST['text'][$a]` in your action 
but in html markup you have

```
<input type="text" required="required" maxlength="160" name="txt[]">
```

So you need either change name of html input to `text` or use `$_POST['txt'][$a]`

Other thing is that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injectio](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)n. You should use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Hey Tomasz, Thanks for your help the txt[] did the trick. I have used some hours and got lost in the woods??